# Unable concatenate has_one_attached files to array for active_storage-send-zip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using **active_storage-send_zip** gem to zip files that are stored for a model. The issue I am having, is that I get AssociationMismatch because it expects every element all files to be an array. I cannot convert ActiveStore:OneAttached as an array. I tried to push the files into an array, but it doesn't work. It stops right on the line for the has_one_attached file. **How can I concatenate my has_many_attached and has_one_attached files & then create a zip that contains all of the files?**

**routes.rb**

```
resources :registration_forms do
  member do
      get :zip_credential_files, constraints: lambda {|req| req.format == :zip}
 end
end
```

**registration_forms_controller.rb**

```
class RegistrationFormsController << ApplicationController
      include ActiveStorage::SendZip
      before_action :set_registration_form, only: %i[....]
        
        
        def zip_credential_files
         documents = @registration_form.personal_documents
         documents << @registration_form.state_id_document
         
        respond_to do |format|
          format.zip {send_zip documents}
        end
     end
    end
```

**Stacktrace**

```
ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in RegistrationFormsController#zip_credential_files

ActiveStorage::Attachment(#...444) expected, got # <ActiveStorage::Attached::One:... >> which is an instance of ActiveStorage::Attached::One(#4.....)
```

Comment: You are close.  `documents << @registration_form.state_id_document.attachment` should do the trick.  Need to get to the attachment itself. https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Attached/One.html

Comment: I'll give it a test run and report back.

Comment: I think it works...But, you have to check if the file is attached? first. I'll do another test run, shortly.